# iterate and filter thru the list of element from xpath?

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, python-requests

```
import requests
import time
from requests_html import HTMLSession

def getTitle(url):
    session = HTMLSession()
    r = session.get(url)
    r.html.render(sleep=1)
    for item in r.html.xpath('//*[@class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal"]'):
        product = item.text



results=getTitle('https://www.amazon.com/s?k=amazon+echo+dot&qid=1605730376&ref=sr_pg_1')

for res in results:
    if "Echo" in results:
        print(res)
    else:
        print("skip")
```

So without the `for res in results` part, it produces a list of product titles from the Amazon link, which is what I need.

**In addition to that, I am trying to eliminate some of the elements I get from the function by finding only those which contain the word "Echo"**

Not sure what kind of object `product=item.text` is.
Tried making results like str(results).

Any helpful tip for filtering out the output of xpath?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This slightly modified code snippet seems to do what you want:

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession


def getTitle(url):
    session = HTMLSession()
    r = session.get(url)
    r.html.render(sleep=1)
    products = []
    for item in r.html.xpath('//*[@class="a-size-medium a-color-base a-text-normal"]'):
        product = item.text
        products.append(product)
    return products


results = getTitle(
    "https://www.amazon.com/s?k=amazon+echo+dot&qid=1605730376&ref=sr_pg_1"
)
filtered_results = []
for index, res in enumerate(results):
    if "echo" in res.lower():
        print(f"[{index}] {res}")
        filtered_results.append(res)
    else:
        print(f"[{index}] skip")
```

Which outputs:

```
[0] Echo Dot (3rd Gen) - Smart speaker with Alexa - Sandstone
[1] All-new Echo Dot (4th Gen) | Smart speaker with Alexa | Charcoal
[2] All-new Echo Dot (4th Gen) | Smart speaker with clock and Alexa | Twilight Blue
[3] Echo Flex - Plug-in mini smart speaker with Alexa
[4] All-new Echo Dot (4th Gen) Kids Edition | Designed for kids, with parental controls | Panda
[5] All-new Echo Dot (4th generation) International Version | Smart speaker with Alexa | Charcoal
[6] Echo Show 8 -- HD smart display with Alexa – stay connected with video calling - Charcoal
[7] Echo Show 5 -- Smart display with Alexa – stay connected with video calling - Sandstone
[8] Echo Dot (3rd Gen) - Smart speaker with Alexa - Plum
[9] skip
[10] All-new Echo Dot (4th Gen) + Amazon Smart Plug | Charcoal
[11] Echo Auto- Hands-free Alexa in your car with your phone
[12] All-new Fire TV Stick and All-new Echo Dot (Charcoal) bundle
[13] All-new Echo Dot (4th Gen) + Amazon Smart Plug | Glacier White
[14] Amazon Echo Power Adapter 21W: Echo (1st and 2nd Gen), Echo Plus (1st Gen), Echo Show (1st Gen)
[15] All-new Echo (4th Gen) | With premium sound, smart home hub, and Alexa | Charcoal
[16] All-new Echo Dot (4th Gen) with clock + Amazon Smart Plug | Twilight Blue
[17] All-new Echo Dot (4th Gen) with clock + Amazon Smart Plug | Glacier White
[18] MightySkins Glossy Glitter Skin for Amazon Echo Dot (3rd Gen) - Purple Flowers | Protective, Durable High-Gloss Glitter Finish | Easy to Apply, Remove, and Change Styles | Made in The USA
```

A few comments unrelated to `xpath`:

- Your function needs to `return` something if you want to be able to iterate on your `xpath` selection.
- Your `in` test in your `if` statement needs to check the `res` item, not the whole `results` list.

Comment: Wow. Simple and brilliant. Will review this over and over. Thank you so much for the extra tips!